# Corollary 4.1 A course in analysis by McDonald

Tags: measure-theory

So I'm currently going through a course in real analysis by McDonald and am getting a little tripped up in the section on the Monotone Convergence Theorem. In the section there is a corollary that states Let $f$ be a nonnegative Lebesgue measureable function and $\{E_n\}_n$ be a sequence of pairwise disjoint Lebesgue measurable sets. Then

$$\int_{\cup_n E_n} f d\lambda = \sum_n \int_{E_n} f d\lambda$$

I will reproduce the proof in the book, but first in the book they use this theorem:

Theorem 4.4: Suppose that $\{f_n\}_n$ is a sequence of nonnegative Lebesgue measurable functions such that $\sum_nf_n$ converges to a real valued function. Then we have for each $E\in \mathcal{M}$

$$\int_E \sum_n f_n d\lambda = \sum_n \int_E f_n d\lambda$$ where $\mathcal{M}$ is the set of Lebesgue measurable functions. Now the proof of the corollary:

Because the $E_n$s are pairwise disjoint we have $\chi_{\cup_nE_n} = \sum_n\chi_{E_n}$. Then by theorem 4.4 we have $$\int_{\cup_n E_n} f d\lambda = \int \chi_{\cup_nE_n} f d\lambda = \int \sum_n  \chi_{E_n}f = \sum_n \int \chi_{E_n}f = \sum_n \int_{E_n} f d\lambda$$ which completes the proof. So my question is how are we using theorem 4.4 when that requires a sequence of nonnegative Lebesgue measurable functions, in the statement it has the sequence, but in our corollary we are just using f which is a nonnegative Lebesgue measurable function?

A lesser important question, but why does the $E_n$s being pairwise disjoint give us that $\chi_{\cup_nE_n} = \sum_n\chi_{E_n}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\int_{\cup_n E_n} f d\lambda = \int \chi_{\cup_nE_n} f d\lambda = \color{blue}{\int \sum_n  \chi_{E_n}f = \sum_n \int \chi_{E_n}f} = \sum_n \int_{E_n} f d\lambda$

Colored equality is the one where the monotone convergence theorem has been used. Think of it like this: $g_n=\sum_{j=1}^n \chi_{E_i} f$ so by the theorem in the third equality below: $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \int\chi_{E_n}f =\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{j=1}^n\int\chi_{E_j}f=\lim_{n\to \infty}\int g_n=\int\lim_{n\to \infty} g_n=\int \sum_{n=1}^\infty\chi_{E_n}f$.

As for why $\chi_{\cup E_n} f=\sum_n \chi_{E_n} f\tag 1$ given $E_i$'s disjoint, take any $x$ in the space. If $x$ doesn't belong to any $E_i$, then both sides of $(1)$ are $0$, and if $x$ belongs to some $E_i$, then it can't belong to $E_j$ for any $j\ne i$ due to disjointness of $E_i$'s so LHS of $(1)$ is $1.f(x)=f(x)$ and RHS is $1.f(x)=f(x)$ as $\chi_{E_j}f(x)=0$ for all $j\ne i$. So you always get LHS =RHS for $(1)$.

Comment: Thank you this really helps! I was glossing over the fact that you can just take $g_n$ as you did!